# performseguewithidentifier works with a delay

Tags: ios, swift

I have such a problem that when I click on the button the `performSegueWithIdentifier()` works with a delay, in approximately five seconds but when I go back and click on the button again, it works immediately, without any delay.
I wonder if there is anyway `performSegueWithIdentifier()` can work without any delay for the first time?

Comment: Can you please share some code like what you are doing on the controller from where you are performing the segue and what you are doing in `viewDidLoad` and `viewDidAppear`

Comment: I delete all the code but this doesn't help,it present with a delay

Comment: That is simply not possible, you must be doing something in one of the controllers. Can you show the code what was there before and what you deleted? Until and unless you give us anything to work on, we can cannot help  you friend.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Na9t70MLaO0EIl2UxEdMgaRDnvmfam8iqoUJNowwd3s/edit

Comment: do you have any process other than performSegueWithIdentifier within that button click ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add in main_queue and try once

```
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
      // add your performseguewithidentifier in here 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(yoursegueIdentifierName,sender: self)
})
```

**Swift-3**

```
 DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // add your performseguewithidentifier in here 
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(yoursegueIdentifierName,sender: self)
}
```

Comment: Sorry but that does not give effect

Comment: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("LoginVC", sender: nil)

Comment: @ՍարգիսԽաչատրյան - can you update the code with my answer

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Na9t70MLaO0EIl2UxEdMgaRDnvmfam8iqoUJNowwd3s/edit

Comment: @ՍարգիսԽաչատրյան - can you upload the project in drop box is not open

Comment: Sorry but I can not